# Paging UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm building an app, where `UICollectionView` Lies on `UITableViewCell`, Here I want `CollectionView` should scroll horizontally, which is happening but i need here it to paging like one cell at a time in a fix position, but what I got here is by scrolling horizontally it scrolls but previous cell displaying little and the display portion become more on passing every cell.

Here is the Demo I have made, please go through the link and let me know where I'm doing wrong, and what to do to get the result as I wanted.

Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13k3JyaWiq1FuzGK4_8WNguXTUYwb-Xu6/view?usp=sharing

Thanks, Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

For this implement, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width  = (collectionView.frame.size.width)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: your tableview height here.. or collectionview cell height)

}
```

also in interfacebuilder of that tableview cell which contains your collectionview, select collectionview and set minimum spacing 0 for both lines and cells and also section insets to 0 as well

[image: interface builder image]

and also  make sure that in interface builder you have set scrolldirection horizontal and pagining enabled true for the collectionview

Comment: no, its not working this way.. change color of every cell you will get it..

Comment: i did change and its working fine, as it should work.. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=14u7q2MTd1jX-mv3kI21t9uh1ZxZN0X8U

isnt this what you wanted.. ? keep your cool and check where you might have made mistake and for cell background color, i used

func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{
        
        let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        
        let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        
        let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        
        return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }

Comment: Okay, I'm up voting you.. Please see my answer, its working like charm now. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the Answer, By putting this delegates Method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width - 10, height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)
    }
```